# Control group in Incomplete Factorial Design

Tags: anova, experiment-design, fractional-factorial

[here](http://www.socialresearchmethods.net/kb/expfact2.php), in title of Incomplete Factorial Design, it is written that

" it is actually impossible to implement a group that simultaneously has several levels of treatment factors and receives no treatment at all."

But i have not understood, in full factorial design we also allow for a treatment combination where all factors are absent, i.e , treatment combination $(1)$, and it works as control.

Where is the difference between the control of full factorial design and incomplete factorial design?

Comment: This seems to be more question of how to code the factors for the analysis, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/372257/how-do-you-deal-with-nested-variables-in-a-regression-model/372258#372258  will help you see this!